# CSS position fixed does not stay fixed when using CodeMirror

Tags: css, codemirror

I have a header bar whose css is the following:

```
header {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10; width: 99.9%;}
```

I am using CodeMirror and sometimes, when editing, the above header bar temporarily jumps to where the cursor is located as indicated in the image below. Is there something that I misunderstood about css position:fixed, or a known issue with CodeMirror, or something else altogether?

[image: Header bar not staying fixed]

Comment: I don't recommend to use fixed, it will also break on most mobile devices. Either use absolute css property or add some javascript if you need the object to be dynamic.

Comment: The site I am working on is definitely not going to be usable on mobile devices.  As the problem I observed occurred infrequently and seemingly randomly, I can not be absolutely certain but it appears as though changing from fixed to absolute might have done the trick.  You might want to rewrite your comment as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to BootStrap for a good example of fixed positioning to lock the header (not for mobile device)

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/